# How can we specify values in a class instance in OWL XML?

Tags: owl, semantic-web

I have just started using OWL XML and was trying to give values to instances of a class but I cannot understand how can that be done. I do know that instances can be specified using **rdf:type**. Please consider a java class Organism as follows:

```
class Organism {
    String name;
    List<Features> features;     
}

class Features {
    int feature1;
    String name;
}
```

This class is extended by Animal and Plant class as follows:

```
class Animal extends Organism {
    int animal_property;
}

class Plant extends Organism {
    int plant_property;
}
```

Now, I want to write an OWL/XML depicting above structure. I have made OWL/XML as below:

```
 <owl:Class rdf:ID="Organism">
     <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
 </owl:Class>

 <owl:Class rdf:ID="Feature">
     <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
 </owl:Class>

 <owl:Class rdf:ID="Animal">
     <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Organism"/>
 </owl:Class>

 <owl:Class rdf:ID="Plant">
     <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Organism"/>
 </owl:Class>

 <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="name">
     <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Organism"/> <!-- can we specify two domain here for Feature and Organism? -->
     <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
 </owl:DatatypeProperty>

 <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="features">
     <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Organism"/> 
     <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Feature"/>
 </owl:ObjectProperty>

 <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="animal_property">
     <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Organism"/> <!-- can we specify two domain here for Feature and Organism? -->
     <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"/>
 </owl:DatatypeProperty>

 <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="plant_property">
     <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Organism"/> **<!-- can we specify two domain here for Feature and Organism? -->**
     <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"/>
 </owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

Please correct me if above definition is incorrect. If want to create instances as follows:

```
Animal -> (name, features, animal_property) -> ("Spider",{feature1,feature2},5}
Plant -> (name, features, plant_property) -> ("Rose",{feature2,feature3},2}

feature1 -> (feature1, name) -> (8,"number of legs");
feature2 -> (feature1, name) -> (2,"tentacles");

feature3 -> (feature1, name) -> (1,"rose_feature_1");
feature4 -> (feature1, name) -> (2,"rose_feature_2");
```

How can I represent this in OWL/XML?

Comment: Your example is not in OWL/XML, it is in RDF/XML. Do you specifically want to know how it's done in RDF/XML, or do you just want to know how this can be done in OWL, regardless of the serialisation format?

Comment: Please use a tool (e.g. Protege) or API to create the ontology and don't start to write RDF/XML. Or at least, write Manchester OWL syntax and use a converter to RDF/XML or whatever you want. But don't write RDF/XML

Comment: @AntoineZimmermannThis is RDF XML serialization in OWL, right? I have used Object property and data property which are a part of OWL, please correct me if I am wrong. So I wanted to know that in this RDF XML serialization, how would I specify values mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AKSWis there any specific reason for this? Any hand written RDF/XML should still be valid if I pass it to protege right?

Comment: Writing RDF by hand is both tedious and error prone. Better to do the modeling in Protege first, and look at the output later. Otherwise you'll spend a lot of time trying to figure out the details of the XML rather than designing your ontology.

Comment: So, it seems that your problem is a modelling problem, not specifically related to RDF/XML. BTW, [OWL/XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-xml-serialization/) is another serialisation format for OWL ontologies.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann Yes. I do not know how should I represent mentioned model. I tried some resources but could not really find how they have represented structure similar to mine(giving values to instances).

Answer (score 0):

Your `name` data property should have only `Feature` as its domain. `Organism` wouldn't be a domain for this property, in the class hierarchy you're planning to create.

Multiple domains can be used in OWL, but note that using a property with two or more domains means that the individuals appearing as subjects belong to the intersection of the domains. I don't think you wish to create individuals that are instance of both `Organism` and `Feature`.

Comment: How do I write instances values, like name="spider", as i have mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, let me tell you that OWL is not an object oriented programming language. You **cannot** model Java classes with OWL. With that said, it is often the case that Java classes correspond to an in-memory representation of something you want to represent knowledge about. Thus, there could be correspondences between an OOP model and an OWL ontology. However, there is no single way of mapping an OOP model to an OWL ontology, and there are pitfalls that should be avoided.

One very common mistake people do when thinking of OWL as an object oriented formalism is to think that classes have attributes, and that attributes or properties belong to a class. In OWL, they don't. While it is sometimes possible to make sense of a sentence like "the property `name` of the class `Organism`", this is as much meaningful in OWL as "the class `Organism` of the property `name`". Classes and properties exist on their own, independently from each other. None belong to the other. However, they can be related in different ways.

Another typical mistake is to misinterpret the relations `domain` and `range` that connect a property to a class. Entities that have a property are typed with *every* domains the property has.

Now, let us go back to your problem. It is very hard to answer your modelling problem without more details about what you are trying to model. As I said, having a Java class is not sufficient to say how the corresponding OWL terms should be defined. For instance, what do you mean with the term "feature"? The attribute `features` of the Java class `Organism` is a list. Is the order important? An `animal_property` is a number?! What is this number representing? Is `name` supposed to be understood in the common sense English word "name"? In my opinion, anything that one can think of can be named, not just organisms or features.

In your case, an intuitive understanding of what you may want have to be guessed based on the choice of English words you've made, and a rough idea of what programming constructs are usually used for. My intuitition is that it is a good idea to map each Java class to an OWL class, and to map inheritance to the `subClassOf` relation.

For properties, it is more complicated. Most Java attributes that have a primitive type map naturally to an OWL datatype property. But not always! OOP classes often contain auxiliary data structures that only make sense for the application logic, yet are irrelevent to the representation of our knowledge of the type of entities. In your model, it is very much possible that the attribute `feature1` in Java class `Features` should not be mapped to an OWL property at all. The `name` attribute in `Organism` could map to the same property as the `name` attribute in `Features`, but possibly not, depending on what you mean. My intuition is that there should be a single `name` property that shoud **not** have any defined domain (such that it could be used safely on any entity).

OOP languages have primitive data types that are very similar to the XML schema datatypes (XSDs). However, the "obvious" mapping is not always the best. With my understanding of the `name` property, I would expect that language tags could be used. If the range is `xsd:string`, then language tagged literals are forbidden.

Based on the name of the property `features` and class `Feature`, I would tend to agree that the range of `features` should be `Feature`, although I do not really understand what `Feature` is supposed to represent. Whether or not the domain should be `Organism` totally depends on what exactly the class `Feature` precisely represents.

Finally, the properties `animal_property` and `plant_property` are mysterious and I have the intuition that they do not represent much of the intrinsic nature of animals and plants. In any case, is there a reason to restrict the size of these integer to fit in an `xsd:int? In general, it is good practice to use`xsd:integer` for numbers that have no particular reason to be bounded. There is no reason to have our representation of knowledge about the world be constrained by the weak 32 bits architectures of our old computers.